# Prove that $10\mid A000793(n\ge16)$

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Prove that if $n\ge16,$then $10\mid g(n),$where $g(n)$ is the largest LCM of partitions of $n$.

For more information,see http://oeis.org/A000793

Here is the list of $g(n)$ for $n>0,$ $g(15)=105,g(16)=140.$
$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 12, 15, 20, 30, 30, 60, 60, 84, 105, 140, 210, 210, 420, 420, 420, 420, 840, 840, 1260, 1260, 1540, 2310, 2520, 4620, 4620, 5460, 5460, 9240, 9240, 13860, \cdots$

If $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k=n,$ and LCM$(a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_k)=g(n),$ then we need to prove that 
at least one of $a_i$ is even, and one of $a_i$ is divisible by 5.

**PS:This is only my conjecture,maybe it's wrong**,see http://oeis.org/A000793/b000793.txt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, Thank you,I copied the wrong list.It's http://oeis.org/A206398,do you know why are they different?I think they should be same.

Comment: I wonder whether more isn't true; for every $m$, there exists $n_0$ such that $n\gt n_0$ implies $m$ divides $g(n)$.

Comment: 206398 looks wrong to me. Maybe you could let them know.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at some of the references at 000793, they might shed some light on the question. In particular, the Nicolas paper on highly composite numbers might say something useful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will first prove the claim by @Gerry Myerson in the comments: For every $m$, there exists $n_0$ such that $n>n_0$ implies $m \mid g(n)$. At the end, I show that $10 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<1550$.

First, a trivial lemma:

**Lemma 1:** If $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_k \geq 2$ are positive integers, then $a_1a_2 \ldots a_k \geq a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_k$.

**Proof:** We proceed by induction on $k$. This is clearly true when $k=1$. When $k=2$, since $(a_1-1)(a_2-1) \geq 1$, we easily get $a_1a_2 \geq a_1+a_2$. Suppose that it holds for $k=i$. Then $a_1a_2 \ldots a_ia_{i+1} \geq (a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_{i-1})+a_ia_{i+1}$ by the induction hypothesis. By the base case where $k=2$, we have $a_ia_{i+1} \geq a_i+a_{i+1}$, so we are done by induction.

Now, suppose that we have $n=x_1+x_2+ \ldots +x_t$, $lcm(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t)=g(n)$. If $x_i$ is neither $1$ nor a prime power for some $i$, then we may write $x_i=a_1a_2 \ldots a_k, k \geq 2$, where each $a_j$ is a prime power. By lemma $1$, we may then replace $x_i$ by $k+1$ terms: $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_k$, and $x_i-(a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_k)$. (The last term is non-existent if equality holds) This will not decrease the lcm of the numbers, so we may safely assume that all $x_i$ are prime powers (or 1).

For a prime $p$, define $f_p(n)=v_p(g(n))$. Clearly if $f_p(n) \geq 1$, then $p^{f_p(n)}$ must be one of the terms in the partition of $n$ with lcm $g(n)$. (We have already assumed that all terms are $1$, or prime powers)

**We want to show that for any positive integer $m$, there are finitely many $n$ s.t. $m \nmid g(n)$. It clearly suffices to show this for $m$ a prime power. ($m=1$ is trivial)**

Let $m=p^a$. Suppose that $m \nmid g(n)$. Then $f_p(n) \leq a-1$.

Consider any prime $q \not =p$. If $q \mid g(n)$, then $q^{f_q(n)}$ is a term in the partition. Define $b_q=\lceil \frac{\log{q}}{\log{p}} \rceil$. Then $p^{b_q}>q$.

If $p^{a-1+b_q}+q^{f_q(n)-1} \leq q^{f_q(n)}$, we may replace $q^{f_q(n)}$ by the $3$ terms $p^{a-1+b_q}$, $q^{f_q(n)-1}$, and $q^{f_q(n)}-(p^{a-1+b_q}+q^{f_q(n)-1})$. (The third term is non-existent if equality holds) Now, $v_p(lcm)$ is now equal to $a-1+b_q \geq a$, and $v_q(lcm)$ is at least $f_q(n)-1$. Since $p^{a-1+b_q}q^{f_q(n)-1}>p^{a-1}q^{f_q(n)} \geq p^{v_p(n)}q^{f_q(n)}$, the lcm of the partition has increased, so $g(n)$ is not the largest lcm, a contradiction.

Therefore $p^{a-1+b_q}+q^{f_q(n)-1}>q^{f_q(n)}$. Thus $p^aq \geq p^{a-1+b_q}>q^{f_q(n)}-q^{f_q(n)-1}=(q-1)q^{f_q(n)-1}$, so $f_q(n)<1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}}$.

If $q \nmid g(n)$, then $f_q(n)=0<1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}}$.

**Thus if $p^a \nmid g(n)$, then $f_q(n)<1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}}$ for all primes $q \not =p$.**

Note that $f_p(n)+1 \leq a<1+\frac{\log{(\frac{p}{p-1}p^a)}}{\log{p}}$.

We proceed to show that if $q$ is sufficiently large (in relation to $p, a$), then $p^a \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow q \nmid g(n)$.

We first prove $2$ lemmas:

**Lemma 2:** Let $S$ be a finite set of primes, and $q$ be a prime s.t. $q^2 \nmid g(n)$. If $\sum_{s \in S}{s^{f_s(n)+1}} \leq q<\prod_{s \in S}{s}$, then $q \nmid g(n)$.

**Proof:** If $q \mid g(n)$, then $f_q(n)=1$, so $q$ appears in the partition. We may clearly replace $q$ by the terms $s^{f_s(n)+1}, s \in S$ and $q-\sum_{s \in S}{s^{f_s(n)+1}}$. Since $\prod_{s \in S}{s^{f_s(n)+1}}>\prod_{s \in S}{s^{f_s(n)}}q$, the lcm of the parition has increased as a result, so we get a contradiction. Therefore $q \nmid g(n)$.

**Lemma 3:** Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime. Then for $i \geq 3$, we have $p_{i+1}^2+p_{i+2}^2+p_{i+3}^2<p_{i}p_{i+1}p_{i+2}$.

**Proof:** By Betrand's postulate, $p_{i+3} \leq 2p_{i+2} \leq 4p_{i+1}$, so $p_{i+1}^2+p_{i+2}^2+p_{i+3}^2<p_{i+1}p_{i+2}+2p_{i+1}p_{i+2}+8p_{i+1}p_{i+2} \leq p_ip_{i+1}p_{i+2}$ for $i \geq 4$. When $i=3$, we clearly have $7^2+11^2+13^2=339<385=5(7)(11)$.

Now, note that for prime $q>p^a$, we have $q-1 \geq p^a$, so $f_q(n)<1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}} \leq 2$. Thus $f_q(n) \leq 1$. Let $c=\max(\pi(p^a), 2) \geq 2$, and consider $q \geq p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2$. Let $d$ be the largest positive integer such that $q \geq p_d^2+p_{d+1}^2+p_{d+2}^2$. Clearly $d \geq c+1 \geq 3$, so by the maximality of $d$ and lemma $3$ we have $q<p_{d+1}^2+p_{d+2}^2+p_{d+3}^2<p_dp_{d+1}p_{d+2}$.

Since $q>p_{d+2}>p_{d+1}>p_d \geq p_{c+1}>p^a$, $f_{p_{d+2}}(n), f_{p_{d+1}}(n), f_{p_d}(n), f_q(n) \leq 1$. Therefore $p_d^{f_{p_d}(n)+1}+p_{d+1}^{f_{p_{d+1}}(n)+1}+p_{d+2}^{f_{p_{d+2}}(n)+1} \leq p_d^2+p_{d+1}^2+p_{d+2}^2 \leq q<p_dp_{d+1}p_{d+2}$, so by lemma $2$ we have $q \nmid g(n)$.

**Therefore, $p^a \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow q \nmid g(n)$ for $q \geq p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2$.**

Combining this with the previous bounds on $f_q(n)$, we get:

$$p^a \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow pg(n) \mid \prod_{q \text{prime} \atop q< p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q^{\left \lfloor 1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}} \right \rfloor}}$$

This gives

$$g(n)<pg(n) \leq \prod_{q \text{prime} \atop q<p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q^{\left \lfloor 1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}} \right \rfloor}}=\prod_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq p^a}{q^{\left \lfloor 1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}} \right \rfloor}}\prod_{q \text{prime} \atop p^a<q<p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q}$$

This clearly implies that

\begin{align}
n<\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq p^a}{q^{\left \lfloor 1+\frac{\log{(\frac{q}{q-1}p^a)}}{\log{q}} \right \rfloor}}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop p^a<q<p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q} & \leq \sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq p^a}{(\frac{q^2}{q-1}p^a)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop p^a<q<p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q} \\
& \leq p^a\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq p^a}{(q+2)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop p^a<q<p_{c+1}^2+p_{c+2}^2+p_{c+3}^2}{q}
\end{align}

We have thus shown that for any positive integer $m$, there exists $n_0$ s.t. $n>n_0$ implies $m \mid g(n)$. In fact, the above bound is easily seen to be $O(m^4)$.

**Application to $m=10$:** We have that $$2 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<2\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq 2}{(q+2)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop 2<q<5^2+7^2+11^2}{q}=3837$$

$$5 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<5\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq 5}{(q+2)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop 5<q<7^2+11^2+13^2}{q}=10261$$

Thus $10 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<10261$.

In fact, we can do much better with a simple refinement. Note that by the above results, $2 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow q \nmid g(n)$ for $q \geq 5^2+7^2+11^2=195$. Observe that $f_2(n)=0$ and $f_p(n) \leq 1$ for $p \geq 3$. Consider $85 \leq q<195$, then since $$2^{f_2(n)+1}+3^{f_3(n)+1}+5^{f_5(n)+1}+7^{f_7(n)+1} \leq 2^1+3^2+5^2+7^2=85 \leq q<195<2(3)(5)(7)$$, we have by lemma $2$ ($f_q(n) \leq 1$) that $q \nmid g(n)$.

The same argument then gives $$2 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<2\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq 2}{(q+2)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop 2<q<85}{q}=880$$

Similarly, $5 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow q \nmid g(n)$ for $q \geq 7^2+11^2+13^2=339$. Observe that $f_5(n)=0$ and $f_p(n) \leq 1$ for $p \geq 5$. Consider $175 \leq q<339$, then since $$5^{f_5(n)+1}+7^{f_7(n)+1}+11^{f_{11}(n)+1} \leq 5^1+7^2+11^2=175 \leq q<339<(5)(7)(11)$$, we have by lemma $2$ ($f_q(n) \leq 1$) that $q \nmid g(n)$.

Now $f_2(n)<\lfloor 1+\frac{\log{2(5)}}{\log{2}} \rfloor=5$ and $f_3(n)<\lfloor 1+\frac{\frac{3}{2}(5)}{\log{3}} \rfloor=3$. Thus $f_2(n) \leq 4, f_3(n) \leq 2$. Consider $113 \leq q<175$, then since $$2^{f_2(n)+1}+3^{f_3(n)+1}+5^{f_5(n)+1}+7^{f_7(n)+1} \leq 2^5+3^3+5+7^2=113 \leq q<175<2(3)(5)(7)$$, we have by lemma $2$ ($f_q(n) \leq 1$) that $q \nmid g(n)$.

The same argument then gives $$5 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<5\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop q \leq 5}{(q+2)}+\sum_{q \text{prime} \atop 5<q<113}{q}=1550$$

Thus $10 \nmid g(n) \Rightarrow n<1550$. The remaining small cases can be easily checked with a computer.

Comment: I'm not sure i will ever read this to the end, but +1 anyways :D